# Is this string replacement enough against SQL injection attacks?

Tags: php, mysql, security, code-injection

I'm trying to evaluate a sort of customized `CMS`. The protection the devoloper used against `SQL` attacks is:

```
 str_replace("'", "\'", $_POST[$variable]);
```

Is this good enough, or there're ways to exploit this to inject `SQL` code?

PS: I know the standard way is using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but I'm trying to get an idea of the general quality of the code.

Comment: If someone enters `\'` then your escaping won't work will it? This becomes `"\'"` (escaped quote) followed by  `'` (unescaped quote)

Comment: the standard way isn't `mysql_real_escape_string`, in fact, `mysql_*` has (finally) begun the deprecation process. The standard way is using prepared statements. Look into `PDO` and `mysqli_*`

Comment: If this sort of wheel-reinventing is present, this is a very bad sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str_replace("'", "\'", $_POST[$variable]);
```

Yes this is vulnerable.

Trivially, the backslash is not escaped, so you can break out of a string literal using a backslash to mask a quote: `hello\' OR 1 --` -> `'hello\\' OR 1 --'`.

Nulls are also not escaped and may cause problems.

Also if East Asian charsets are in use, a multibyte sequence may be used to mask the quote. (Note this is NOT the case for UTF-8, as UTF-8 does not allow `'` as a trailing byte.)

Also this escaping format is only suitable for MySQL. If any other database is used, or the ANSI-compliant string literal option is used in MySQL, then it will be ineffective, as the standard escape is to double the quote, not backslash.

The code is useless. At best it shows someone is aware that SQL injection exists, but it exhibits no real understanding of the actual problem.

Answer (score 8):

No. Throw in some UTF8 character and this would either garble the code or be escaped.

Use mysqli / PDO or if you must, use mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: If they cooked up their own instead of using a standard function, I wouldn't trust the rest of the code base.

Comment: You should add "prepared statements"; just switching to mysqli or PDO does not help much if you write code like that...

Answer (score 1):

SQL Injections can come in many forms.

If there was a query that performs a where clause on a numeric field (think PIN Number) it could easily be injected.

Something harmless looking for a match on the user entered number:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ID = 1
```

Could turn in to something that always matches

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ID = 1 OR 1 = 1
```

Using the vendor specific escape functions or prepared statements is the way to go.